# How to set php class attribute?

Tags: php, class, methods, attributes

I got a problem

```
class a
{
     public $aa=1;
     public function dd(){
       $this->aa = 2;
     }
     public function gg(){
       echo   $this->aa ;
     }
}
```

how come in the go method `echo $this->aa` still be '1'?

Comment: dont use do, for, while etc as function names buddy, but do accept answers. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `do` is reserved keyword in PHP.

[Demo of `do` as method name.](http://codepad.org/EzUkPbUi) (An error)

[Demo without `do`, successfull outputs 2](http://codepad.org/8c3TgJi1)

You should change method name from `do` to something else since it is reserved keyword used in [`do-while`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php) loop.

Comment: Indeed: _"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DO, expecting T_STRING in [...] on line 6"_.

Comment: @paynestrike: See second demo in my answer, it works. here is it: http://codepad.org/8c3TgJi1

Answer (score 6):

Because function `dd()` is never executed